# all possible combinations to divide pack of candies

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I have problem to solve and I'm stuck, I don't know how to start.

Suppose I have R childrens and S candies. I want to divide candies between childrens. Each child can get 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 candies. How to find all the possibilities of such a division?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void solve(int r, int s) {
    if (s == 0)
    {
        cout << "no more candies" << endl;
        return;
    }
    
    if (r == 0)
    {
        cout << "last child" << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4 && j <= s; ++j)
    {
        cout << "r: " << r  << " j: " << j << endl;

        solve(r-1, s - j);
    }
}

int main () {
    int r, s;
    cin >> r >> s;
    solve(r, s);
    return 0;
}
```

For now I have sth like this, I see in output that I have solutions here, but I don't know how to grab and store all possibilities into for example vector.

Comment: You should start by writing program to read input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store counts and save variants at the last recursion level

```
vector<int> counts;
vector<vector<int>> sol;

void solve(int r, int s) {
    if (s == 0)
    {
        sol.push_back(counts);
        return;
    }

    if (r == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= 4 && j <= s; ++j)
    {
        counts[r - 1] += j;
        solve(r - 1, s - j);
        counts[r - 1] -= j;
    }
}

int main() {
    int r, s;
    r = 3;
    s = 5;
    for (int j = 0; j < r; ++j)
        counts.push_back(0);
    solve(r, s);
    for (int i = 0; i < sol.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sol[i].size(); j++) {
            cout << sol[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```